# Switching DEBUG and ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py automatically with Django

Tags: django

I think I applied `DEBUG` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `settings.py` as the situation demands with `if` statements before.
But I forgot how.
Now, I chenge `DEBUG` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS` everytime I upload my project to `heroku`.

For instance, under the local environment,

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

when I upload,

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['something.herokuapp.com']
```

But, I feel tiresome about changing these.
Would you please teach me how to change these settings automatically, I mean, the way to make the server apply or interpret these settings automatically?

`Django-1.9.2`

Comment: This is something that actually got covered in the [SO Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/942/settings/3580/using-environment-variables-to-manage-settings-across-servers#t=201610121047399687075)

Comment: Aside from that, use a separate settings file for local dev

Comment: @Sayse is correct, to make it more sexier create file local_dev.py 
`DEBUG=TRUE
 ALLOWED_HOST = [something]`

In setting import the local_dev.py file

and import the variables, so that you do not need to change setting each and every time

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Sayse and Niranj. I will try to make a setting file for local. Thanks.